# How to get standard deviations using predict?

Tags: r, predict, interaction

I am trying to plot a three-way interaction. First, i use `expand.grid` to create different combinations of my variables. Then i use `predict` to get the predicted values. It works well, however, i would like to get the standard deviation or confidence interval. Once i include the option `se.fit = T` in `predict`, i get back some results that i cannot interpret as two combinations get one predicted value and the other two get a range of four outcomes. I am not sure if the `se.fit = T` option is wrong in this context or whether the issue is in my interpretation of the results. Could someone help please?

This is the code that works without the `se.fit` option:

```
set.seed(20170925) 
dat <- data.frame(time=gl(n = 2,k = 5000),
                  y= rnorm(10000, mean=1000, sd=400),
                  a=factor(sample(1:2, 10000, replace=TRUE)),
                  b=factor(sample(1:2, 10000, replace=TRUE)),
                  c=factor(rep(rep(1:3,times=c(2500,2500,5000)),2)))

m = lm(y ~ a*b*c, data=dat)
pred <- expand.grid(a=factor(1:2),b=factor(1:2), c=factor(1, levels=c(1,2,3)))
pred$y <- predict(m,pred)
```

To add the `se.fit` option, we run the same code but change the last line to:

```
pred$y <- predict(m,pred, se.fit = T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`predict` now gives you a list, you just have to pick out the elements of it, perhaps like this:

```r
p <- predict( m, pred, se.fit=TRUE )

pred$y <- p$fit
pred$se.fit <- p$se.fit
```

EDIT: kept it simpler